# Changing z-order of views that aren't related

Tags: ios, uitableview, z-order

How do I change the order of views displayed, when the two views I want to rearrange are not related?

I am trying to work on someone else's code, and they have a class which is a subclass of UITableViewController. I want to put a background in, so I put it as a subview of self.view .

The problem is, it's displayed in front of the table, and the table is located as self.tableView, not self.view.tableView . Since the two views aren't together, I can't use the sendSubviewToBack method.

self is the viewController class I'm working on.

Any ideas?

```
UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"editInfoBG.png"]];
background.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 416);
[self.view addSubview:background];

// Doesn't work, the table is not a subview of self.view
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:background];
```

Comment: don't forget to accept your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add subviews into your viewcontroller, you should use a subclass of `UIViewController` with manually added `UITableView` as subview and implementing the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols instead of using `UITableViewController`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't want to remove anything that belonged to the guy who made the program, and I didn't really know what I was doing, but I ended up just making a new table with the same data source and delegate as the old table, and that worked (the original table just hides behind the background image). I added the new table as a subview to self.view, and then I could order it with the background.

Answer (score 0):

you can insert the background before the tabeview like this
`[self.view insertSubview:background belowSubview:self.tableView.view];`

Comment: Did you really try your approach?

Comment: What is self.tableView? UITableView or UITableViewController

Comment: Yeah,your approach works too, but the background view will also scroll when you scroll the table view